# Unable to change the target field of a managed rollup summary. What's the reason behind that?

Tags: managed-package, formula, isv, roll-up-summary

I just found out that I reference the wrong field in my SUM Rollup Summary field. It is managed and was already released. And it seems I cannot change this anymore.

1) Why is this not allowed while formula fields are changeable all the time? I would like to understand the technical reason for this.

2) Am I right that only the creation of a new field and the later [deletion of the old managed field from my package](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=viewing_deleted_components.htm&language=en_US) can fix this?